# Não é possível visualizar detalhes de eventos criado no schedule do primefaces

Tags: primefaces, java

Isso esta me intrigando tem um tempo, uso no projeto o schedule do primefaces para adicionar eventos, ate ai tudo bem, todos os computadores adicionam e mandam para o database online, existe também um método que lista todos os detalhes de cada evento quando se clica nele, só que alguns computadores da certo ver eventos cadastrados por um mas em outro PC não é possível, não faço ideia alguma de porque isso está acontecendo e nem de como resolver.

Eu criei esse no meu PC e eu consigo ver.
[image: localhost]
Esse foi criado em outro PC e ainda consigo ver ( do meu pc).
[image: outra maquina com view]
Esse foi criado em outro PC e não consigo ver ( porem em ainda outro PC sem ser o que eu consigo ver os eventos, consegue mostrar os desse.)
[image: outro sem view]

Então talvez tenha ficado confuso, me parece que os eventos estão aparecendo em pares ( não sei se realmente são pares) mas sei que os 4 que testei 2 conseguem ver os detalhes dos eventos deles e os outros não.

Detalhe todos os eventos aparecem no scheuld para todos os PC mas os detalhes não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto esta relacionado aos eventos Ajax

Ou seja, quando você define (ou não, **mas deveria limitar o escopo de atualização da pagina**) a propriedade process="@this" processa só a tag current, se usar a propriedade update="@form", ai ele atualiza a arvore de componentes parent form(definição a nível didático ajuste para seu contexto).

Porque funciona a primeira vez? ou segunda até uma hora não funcionais mais. Você atualiza a árvore de componentes do JSF ultima vez antes de dar erro, mas não notificou o próximo que determinada parte da pagina mudou.

Nesse, vai e vem, o scop da view **(árvore de componente esta desatualizado, com relação ao estado que ele sabe, ai acontece isso)**

Solução sugerida, quando se tem um componente complexo, use um **p:outpuPanel,** e processe e atualize ele, sempre visível, diminui a complexidade dessa atualização do DOM.

Isso parece complexo, mas é Ajax e seus conceitos, Atualizando o DOM e não notificando todos. tipo tinha uma rua, agora tem um buraco na rua, mas não tem placa avisando (**então problema**) para não ter problema avise todos ou a quem interessa.